# Proper way to enqueue a generated script that isn't in a .js file?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

What's the proper way for loading a script via WordPress that isn't in a `.js` file?
I'm generating some javascript on the fly based on some field options in a plugin. I want to load it into the page, but I want to do it the right way.

How should I proceed?

Comment: This will help you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24851/wp-enqueue-inline-script-due-to-dependancies

Comment: That great, wp_localize_script worked perfect. Nice and clean, thanks!

Comment: Add it as an answer ans accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using wp_localize_script(). This allowed me just to send the PHP variables as parameters directly to a javascript file. Also useful for doing translations in javascript files. And then I didn't have to do messy inline javascript.