# WOW.js Script Tag Initialization Header/Footer

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, headers

hope things are going well.

I'm attempting to use WOW.js http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html with animate.css to add animations to my site. WOW.js requires me to initialize it by adding the following in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script>
 new WOW().init();
</script>
```

The theme I'm using, JointsWP, is utilizing wp_register_style, wp_enqueue_style, and wp_enqueue_script to link the js and css files.

```
// register wow.js & animate.css
    wp_register_style( 'animate-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/css/animate.css', array(), '', 'all' );
    wp_register_script( 'wow-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/vendor/wow.min.js', array(), '', 'all' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'animate-stylesheet' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wow-js' );
```

I've successfully linked the required css and js file using these WP functions.. I'm having trouble adding the inline  `new WOW().init();` method to the page source. What would be the best way to add this to the page?  I've attempting adding the function referenced in this link [wp enqueue inline script due to dependancies](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24851/wp-enqueue-inline-script-due-to-dependancies) but I wasn't able to successfully implement it. I've also added the script tag code to the header.php, but the animation isn't being applied.

I greatly appreciate any help that can be provided.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme *should* enqueue styles and scripts on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook, per Codex recommendations.

```
function theme_enqueue_scripts()
// register wow.js & animate.css
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/css/animate.css', array(), '', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wow-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/vendor/wow.min.js', array(), '', 'all' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Then your initization script can be added to the `wp_head` hook.

```
function wpa_135542(){?>
<script>
 new WOW().init();
</script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpa_135542' );
```