# How to change script order?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I'm using `wp_enqueue_scripts` to add jquery and other libraries. But now I wanna add a `<script>alert('hello');</script>` before a certain library loads, how could i achieve that?

Comment: For those wondering how to do this: [This](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24851/wp-enqueue-inline-script-due-to-dependancies?rq=1) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

[`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) has `$deps` parameter which exactly does what you need.

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer )
```

Let's say that your custom code is in a file named `custom.js` which is enqueued with a handle `my-custom` and you want this to be loded before `my-script1` which is en-queued with a handle.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom', '/path/to/customjs', array() );

wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script1', '/path/to/script1js', array('my-custom') );
```

The above code says that `my-custom` is a dependency for `my-script1`.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that, I created another file and enqueued it before this library and it works. But my question is can you add a `<script>alert('hello');</script>` tag before a certain library is loaded?

Comment: You mean just before a library like `script.js` but after `script1.js`

Comment: Yes, exactly! Is that possible?